# Динамическое создание кнопок C# WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

Мне необходимо на форме создать поворачиваемые рукоятки (кликом мышки меняется положение рукоятки с вертикального в горизонтальный и обратно).
Рукоятки расположены квадратом, как 2-мерный массив NxN.
Число N должно быть настраиваемое.
Я решил создать массив из поворачиваемых кнопок.

```
private Button[,] CreateButtons(int quantity)
{
    Button[,] buttons = new Button[quantity, quantity];
    for (int i = 0; i < quantity; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < quantity; j++)
        {
            buttons[i, j] = new Button();
            buttons[i, j].Width = 50;
            buttons[i, j].Height = 20;
            buttons[i, j].VerticalAlignment = System.Windows.VerticalAlignment.Top;
            buttons[i, j].HorizontalAlignment = System.Windows.HorizontalAlignment.Left;
            buttons[i, j].Margin = new Thickness(10);
        }
    }
    return buttons;
}

private void AddToWrapPanel(int quantity, Button[,] buttons)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < quantity; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < quantity; j++)
        {
            wrapPanel.Children.Add(buttons[i, j]);
        }
}

private int GetQuantityButtons()
{
    ComboBoxItem item = (ComboBoxItem)comboBox1.SelectedItem;
    int count = int.Parse((string)item.Content);
    return count;
}

private void СreateButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (wrapPanel.Children.Count > 0)
        wrapPanel.Children.Clear();
    int count = GetQuantityButtons();
    Button[,] buttons = CreateButtons(count);
    AddToWrapPanel(count, buttons);
}
```

Вот что у меня есть. Но проблема на лицо - все кнопки расположены в ряд. Как мне добиться матричного расположения?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Очевидно, надо использовать для этого более подходящие инструменты компоновки. К примеру заменить WrapPanel на UniformGrid и привязать(установить вручную) размеры  в ComboBox к значению Rows и Columns.

```
<ComboBox Name="cmbBox">
    <ComboBoxItem>2</ComboBoxItem>
    <ComboBoxItem>4</ComboBoxItem>
    <ComboBoxItem>8</ComboBoxItem>
</ComboBox>
<UniformGrid 
    Columns="{Binding ElementName=cmbBox, Path=SelectedItem.Content}" 
    Rows="{Binding ElementName=cmbBox, Path=SelectedItem.Content}">
</UniformGrid>
```